# How can i return response only when all mongoose model.save() already saved in express js?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing some express mongo restful apps, and I already create a method for scrape data from a website and save to MongoDB using mongoose. I really confused about how can I return the response for client when the data I loop over each and call model.save() and wait for the loop to stop or success then gives the response to the client.

here's my method to scrapes the data and loop over an each then call the mongoose save() to save one by one the data over the each.

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    let url = 'https://www.bi.go.id/id/moneter/informasi-kurs/transaksi-bi/'

    await axios.get(url)
        .then(async response => {
            let html = response.data;
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let box = $('.box_gray').html()
            let insertedDocs = [];
            let coba = await $(box).find('.table1 > tbody > tr').slice(1, 26).each(async (i, elem) => {
                let arrayData = [];
                $(elem).find('td').slice(0, 4).each((i, elem) => {
                    arrayData.push($(elem).text().trim())
                })

                // get currency ref id
                Currency.findOne({code: arrayData[0]}).exec(async (err, currency) => {
                    if (err) return res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
                    if (currency) {
                        // set object
                        let currencyDataObj = {
                            '_currency': '',
                            'value': '',
                            'sell': '',
                            'buy': ''
                        }
                        currencyDataObj._currency = currency._id
                        currencyDataObj.value = parseFloat(arrayData[1])
                        currencyDataObj.sell = parseFloat(arrayData[2].replace(/[,]/g, ''))
                        currencyDataObj.buy = parseFloat(arrayData[3].replace(/[,]/g, ''))
                        // insertedDocs.push(currencyDataObj)

                        let currencyData = new CurrencyData(currencyDataObj);

                        const newCurrencyData = await currencyData.save();
                        console.log(newCurrencyData)
                        // let successResponse = {
                        //     status: 'success',
                        //     message: `success save kurs data to db with id ${newCurrencyData._id}`
                        // }
                        // res.json(successResponse);
                    } else {
                        console.log('dont have an id', arrayData[0])
                    }
                })
            })

            Promise.all([coba]).then(values => {
                console.log(values);
            });
        })
});

module.exports = router;
```

Schema

```
const currencySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code: {type: String, uppercase: true, required: true, unique: true, dropDups: true},
    symbol: {type: String, required: true},
    digitalCode: {type: Number, required: true},
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    country: {type: String, required: true},
    currencyData: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CurrencyData'}]
})

const currencyDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _currency: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Currency'},
    value: {type: Number, required: true},
    sell: {type: Number, required: true},
    buy: {type: Number, required: true},
    lastUpdatedDateISO: {type: Date},
})

exports.Currency = mongoose.model('Currency', currencySchema);
exports.CurrencyData = mongoose.model('CurrencyData', currencyDataSchema);
```

I already try promise.all() but it does not wait for the mongoose.save() finished.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `await` is a syntactic sugar for `.then`, you aren't supposed to use them together.

Comment: Can you provide `CurrencyData` and `Currency` schema so it's easier to reproduce?

Comment: @Owl i already update the schema, hope it helps